# mock json object in some other format javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have one variable with json object.

```
 var seriesData = [{
                        feederId: "TUR 112",
                        businessEventCode: "LowVoltage",
                        servicePointEventCount: 4
                    }, {
                        feederId: "TUR 112",
                        businessEventCode: "HighVoltage",
                        servicePointEventCount: 2
                    }, {
                        feederId: "ABC",
                        businessEventCode: "LowVoltage",
                        servicePointEventCount: 4
                    }, {
                        feederId: "ABC",
                        businessEventCode: "HighVoltage",
                        servicePointEventCount: 1
                    }];
```

I want to Mock this data into this json formet

```
var MockService= [{
                feederId: "TUR 112",
                servicePointEventLowCount: 4,
                servicePointEventHighCount: 2
            }, {
                feederId: "ABC",
                servicePointEventLowCount: 6,
                servicePointEventHighCount:3 
            }];
```

For that My code :

```
if (seriesData) {
                var mockdata= [];
                for (var i = 0; i < seriesData.length; i++) {
                    var data = {};
                    data.feederId = seriesData[i].feederId;
                    if (seriesData[i].businessEventCode == 'LowVoltage') {
                        data.servicePointEventLowCount = seriesData[i].servicePointEventCount;
                    } else {
                        data.servicePointEventHighCount = seriesData[i].servicePointEventCount;
                    }
                    mockdata.push(data);
                }
            }
                var seriesDataMock = mockdata;
```

I am getting response as -

```
[{
            feederId: "TUR 112",
            servicePointEventLowCount: 4,
            },  {
                feederId: "TUR 112",
                servicePointEventHighCount: 2
            }, {
                feederId: "ABC",
                servicePointEventLowCount: 6,
            }, {
                feederId: "ABC",
                servicePointEventLowCount: 6,
            }];
```

But I want it to be like this--

```
 [{
                feederId: "TUR 112",
                servicePointEventLowCount: 4,
                servicePointEventHighCount: 2
            }, {
                feederId: "ABC",
                servicePointEventLowCount: 6,
                servicePointEventHighCount:3 
            }];
```

Combined values for feederID...

Please guide me if I m missing something.

Thanks!

Comment: Please don´t use uppercase identifiers (`Mockdata`) for variables that are not constructors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set your Mockdata to an empty array, then you proceed to overwrite the same properties for each iteration. I think you want to append data objects for each iteration like this:

pseudo:

```
for (var i = 0; i < seriesData.length; i++) {
  var data = {};
  data.feederId = seriesData[i].feederId;
  Mockdata.push(data);
  ...
}
```

EDIT: I read your updated question and it seems like you want to merge each two sets into one? An easy way would be to do this instead:

```
for (var i = 0; i < seriesData.length; i+=2) {
  var data = {};
  data.feederId = seriesData[i].feederId;
  data.servicePointEventLowCount = seriesData[i].servicePointEventCount;
  data.servicePointEventHighCount = seriesData[i+1].servicePointEventCount;
  Mockdata.push(data);
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. now i am getting 

[{
            feederId: "TUR 112",
            servicePointEventLowCount: 4,
            },  {
                feederId: "TUR 112",
                servicePointEventHighCount: 2
            }, {
                feederId: "ABC",
                servicePointEventLowCount: 6,
            }, {
                feederId: "ABC",
                servicePointEventLowCount: 6,
            }];

Comment: But I want that object/array should be like this format
             [{
                 feederId: "TUR 112",
                 servicePointEventLowCount: 4,
                 servicePointEventHighCount: 2
             }, {
                 feederId: "ABC",
                 servicePointEventLowCount: 6,
                 servicePointEventHighCount:3 
             }];

Comment: Edited my question according to u... can u able to help now.

Comment: +1 and answer is accepted.. By seeing this I must say I need to work on condition structure/looping and all... Thanks dude.... It is very helpful.. :)